# Run .exe from Java service

Tags: java, windows

Is it possible to run a .exe from a java program that is running as a windows service?
I have a java spring application that calls a .exe within the code, when i run it from my IDE it runs perfectly fine but as soon as i wrap ma java jar using nssm and run it as a windows service it fails to run the .exe file.

Comment: and why does it fail? maybe you should look into using another language. Java isn't the most logical choice for a windows service

Comment: That's actually more likely to be related to executing the exe from a service than from the service being Java. Applications launched via services by default don't have access to any UI components, if I remember correctly and that can confuse many executables.

Comment: Often a service runs under a different user with less rights. You should post the error message.

Comment: I'd start by checking the program behaves correctly when run from a command prompt. The IDE could be doing all sorts of things that affect the runtime environment.

Comment: @Stultuske -- Almost all middleware and integration software is written in Java. Whether it's a logical choice for a Windows service is neither here not there. If that's what you've got, it's what you've got.

Comment: @KevinBoone i have run it from the command line and it works perfectly fine so i dont think it has anything to do with the IDE but more to do with what vanje and JoachimSauer are saying